# Mystery recursive function python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def mystery_code(n):
    return mystery_recursive(n, n-1)

def mystery_recursive(a, b):
    if b<=0:
        return 0
    else:
        c=mystery_recursive(a,b-1)
        if a%b==0:
            c+=b
        return c
```

Could someone please help me understand what this code does?

Comment: What do you think it does so far?

Comment: This looks a lot like homework that I assigned to my students not too long ago... :-)

Comment: Have you tried running it and seeing what happens?  You can tell it won't mess up your computer just by looking at it, so...

Comment: I guess doing `print ','.join([str(mystery_code(i)) for i in range(1,20)])` and throwing that at the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/) would be cheating, right?

Comment: I'm not too fluent in python but shouldn't be c initialised before addition?

Comment: @zubergu it is, it receives its first value from `mystery_recursive`.

Comment: @zubergu it is, two lines above the `+=` assignment. But it's hard to see because the teacher didn't follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). (No spaces around operators and one-letter variable names are a habit I often see with mathematicians / scientists, unfortunately).

Answer (score 6):

It computes the sum of proper divisors of `n`.

If you step through the code you'll see it calls, e.g., `mystery_recursive(5, 4)` and then recursively `mystery_recursive(5, 3)`, `mystery_recursive(5, 2)`, `mystery_recursive(5, 1)`, `mystery_recursive(5, 0)`. It'll then return `0` because `b <= 0`.

In each of these calls, it assigns the result of a call to `c` and if `a % b == 0` (i.e., `a` can be divided by `b`) then it adds `b` to `c`. So you'll end up with a sum of the proper divisors of `n`.

Comment: more like sum of **distinct factors** of `n`.

Comment: @tMJ what is the difference between distinct factors and divisors (definition-wise)?

Comment: @SimeonVisser: proper divisors, though, right?  It doesn't count `n`.

Comment: @DSM: let me add that to the answer; given that it calls with `n` and `n - 1` it indeed excludes `n`.

Comment: Correction: the term is `proper divisors`, I see you have already updated it. :)

Answer (score 0):

As already told by Simeon Visser the above code computes the sum of proper divisors of n.

if your function call is:

> mystery_code(12)

then it will call the mystery recursive function (mystery_recursive(a, b)) in your code as:

> mystery_recursive(12, 11)

Once the recursive function started to execute it will keep on calling itself until the condition b<=0 satisfies. In this case mystery_recursive(12, 0) will return a value of '0' to the variable 'c' to its called function mystery_recursive(12, 1). Then, beginning with the above mystery function (mystery_recursive(12, 1)) the 'c' value will be computed and returned to their respective calling functions of the same until the called function mystery_recursive(12, 11).

Output in this case: 16

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it helps to convert this recursive function to an interative version

```
def mystery_recursive(a, b):
    c = 0
    while True:
        if b <= 0:
            return c
        if a % b == 0:
            c += b
        b -= 1
```

It's still a bit clumsy, so try to convert it to a sum generator expression

```
def mystery_recursive(a, b):
    return sum(b for b in range(b, 0, -1) if a % b == 0)
```

You can even roll that back into `mystery_code`

```
def mystery_code(n):
    return sum(b for b in range(n - 1, 0, -1) if n % b == 0)
```